# Regarding the Expenditure Function Underlying a Bliss Point

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics

I've been looking at expenditure systems and have been really interested in the behaviour of the demand system that underlies bliss points:

Consider the bliss point utility function of the following form:

$$U(x_1,x_2)=-(x_1-\delta_1)^2-(x_2-\delta_2)^2$$

for two dimensions the corresponding hicksian demands are:

$$x_1^c=\delta_1-\left[\frac{\bar{U}}{1+\frac{p_2}{p_1}}\right]^\frac{1}{2}$$
$$x_2^c=\delta_2-\left[\frac{\bar{U}}{1+\frac{p_1}{p_2}}\right]^\frac{1}{2}$$

It follows that the expenditure function is:
$$e(p_1,p_2,\bar{U})=p_1\delta_1-p_1\left[\frac{\bar{U}}{1+\frac{p_2}{p_1}}\right]^\frac{1}{2}+p_2\delta_2-p_2\left[\frac{\bar{U}}{1+\frac{p_1}{p_2}}\right]^\frac{1}{2}$$

Obviously expenditure functions can be much larger. however I'm having a hard time for generating a expenditure function for a number of $n$ goods.

**tldr** What would the hicksian demands look like for the utility function:
$$U(\mathbf{x})=-\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\delta_i)^2$$

Answer (score 2):

Usually the change in variables $X=x-\delta$ allows to write
$$ e(p,u) = \max_{x \geq 0}\{ p'x : U(x-\delta) \geq u \} =  \max_{X \geq -\delta} \{ p'X : U(X) \geq u \} + p'\delta $$
and so $ e(p,u) = E(p,u) + p'\delta.$

Answer (score 0):

Edit: My previous answer contained a mistake for the case where $x$ is restricted to $\mathbb{R}_{+}^{n}$. I removed this case from my answer.

Take $\bar{U} > 0$. Let's denote $\delta = (\delta_{1}, \ldots, \delta_{n})$ and $p = (p_{1}, \ldots, p_{n})$. Assume $p \neq 0$. 
We want to solve
\begin{align*}
\min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}} p \cdot x
\qquad 
\text{s.t.}\quad
- (x - \delta) \cdot (x - \delta) \geq - \bar{U}.
\end{align*}

Let's first note that a solution must satisfy $(x - \delta) \cdot (x - \delta) = \bar{U}$. 
This is because the left side of the constraint is continuous in $x$, and because every neighbourhood of $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ contains a point $x^{\prime}$ such that $p\cdot x^{\prime} < p \cdot x$ (since $p \neq 0$).

Setting up a Lagrangian, we solve
\begin{align*}
\min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}, \lambda\in\mathbb{R}} p \cdot x
+ \lambda\left(
(x - \delta) \cdot (x - \delta) - \bar{U}
\right).
\end{align*}
The first order conditions are
$$
p + 2 \lambda (x - \delta) = (0, \ldots, 0)
$$
and
$$
(x - \delta) \cdot (x - \delta) - \bar{U} = 0.
$$
Note that $\lambda$ cannot equal zero as otherwise the first FOC is contradicted. The first FOC is therefore equivalent to $(x - \delta) = - p / (2\lambda)$.
Plugging this expression for $(x - \delta)$ into the second FOC, 
$$
\frac{p \cdot p}{4 \lambda^{2}} = \bar{U}
$$
and hence $\lambda = \sqrt{\frac{p\cdot p}{4 \bar{U}}}$. 
Finally, 
$$
x = \delta + p \frac{1}{2\delta} = \delta + p \sqrt{\frac{\bar{U}}{p\cdot p}}
$$

To gain a geometric intuition, let's denote by $\Vert\cdot\Vert$ the Eucliden norm on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and observe that the set of feasible choices is
$$
\left\lbrace x \in\mathbb{R}^{n}\colon \Vert\delta - x \Vert \leq \sqrt{\bar{U}}\right\rbrace.
$$
This is nothing but the closed ball of radiuc $\sqrt{\bar{U}}$ around $\delta$. 
Minimizing the linear function $x\mapsto p \cdot x$ involves finding the point on the boundary of the ball where a level set of $x\mapsto p \cdot x$ is tangent to the ball.
We find this point by traveling from the ball's center at $\delta$ in the direction of $-p$, i.e. orthogonal to the hyperplane, until we reach the boundary.

Here's an alternate proof that doesn't use any stuff involving Lagrangians:
As before, we may restrict attention to points $y$ satisfying $\Vert\delta - y \Vert = \sqrt{\bar{U}}$. 
Any such point may be written as $y = \delta -  (\delta - y)\frac{\sqrt{\bar{U}}}{\Vert \delta - y \Vert}$.
Consider the point $x = \delta - p \frac{\sqrt{\bar{U}}}{\Vert p \Vert}$.
We claim that $p\cdot x \leq p \cdot y$ for any such point $y$ on the boundary. This is the case if and only if
\begin{align*}
p\cdot (\delta - y) \frac{1}{\Vert \delta - y \Vert}
\leq 
p\cdot p \frac{1}{\Vert p \Vert}.
\end{align*}
The right side equals $\Vert p \Vert$.
As for the left side, by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, 
\begin{align*}
p\cdot (\delta - y)  \frac{1}{\Vert \delta - y \Vert} \leq 
\Vert p \Vert \Vert \delta - y \Vert \frac{1}{\Vert \delta - y \Vert} = \Vert p\Vert,
\end{align*}
and so we're done. Moreover, the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality holds strictly unless $y - \delta$ is a multiple of $p$. In that case, however, either $p = \delta - y$ or $y$ does not lie on the boundary. So the point $x$ is in fact the unique minimizer.

Comment: Hi, looks like you're on to something. but it seems that you made a mistake.your solved FOC should be $(x-\delta)=-\frac{p}{2\lambda}$.

Comment: You're right, that sign is wrong, but the rest of the argument is unchanged. I'll edit the answer